# json post request size limit (now a verified php-mysqli bug)

Tags: php, json, apache2

I'm sending a request to my PHP application through a JSON-encoded ajax request (form process).  A post-request with character length of 4174 is successfully processed and the result is received correctly.  Adding one additional character to the request causes my application to loop infinitely until Apache2 seg-faults.  There are only 2 fields, one for a 3-digit id, and the rest is text from a text area.

I'm using the Zend Framework to drive my application, Apache2.2.3, PHP 5.2.8, JSON plugin version 1.2.1, MySQL 5.0.77

Anyone have any ideas...

here is another update::
    tracked this issue to NOT a json request problem, but an issue with the query i am running.  I'm performing an INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query that inflates the text size of the query.  I can run this query find from the command line, however from PHP it's failing.  Currently investigating the issue.  Anyone interested could see the query here..

** this is a bug with the mysqli plugins for php, for some reason the db handler doesn't like this code.  If/when I have time to properly test, you'll see my results.**

```
INSERT INTO element_attribute_values (ElementAttributeId,ElementId,value) VALUES  (1,'553','444st text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this itext this itext this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test tex this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is sotext this ime test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test tex tesxthis is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is fsome test texttext this i this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is sometext this i test text this is some test text this is some test text this is sothis is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text thisf iffffffff4444') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value='444st text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this itext this itext this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test tex this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is sotext this ime test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test tex tesxthis is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is fsome test texttext this i this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is sometext this i test text this is some test text this is some test text this is sothis is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text this is some test text thisf iffffffff4444'
```

Comment: Please report back when you know more!

Comment: Of course, an Apache crash probably means there's a bug in the PHP module. You probably want to find out what PHP function is crashing and find a workaround. Can you track what line in your code is the one that's making it all crash?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is related or not but I was using jQuery recently using the $.ajax() method to submit POST data from a text field to a php script. The php script would then parse the data (XML) for the bits of information that I needed. I noticed an error on my firephp output that it was unable to parse the XML from the POSTed form. I then had it output the strlen() and the data and noticed it was cutting it from around 7k bytes down to 268 (or 256 or something I forget the exact amount). This made it an incomplete and not valid XML pile of data. I fixed this by using the $.post() method instead. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check the length of your string, and if it's over the limit, split it up. Run the first portion in the insert, then do a `+=` update on the field with the second portion. It's a bit crude, but it gets around the bug.